# select multiple pictures and set them in different pictureboxes

Tags: c#, picturebox

I want to select multiple images and shown them in different pictureboxes. for this my code is

```
 private void btnChoose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       DialogResult dr = this.openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
       if (dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
       {
           // Read the files
           foreach (String file in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
           {
               // Create a PictureBox.
               try
               {
                   PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
                   Image loadedImage = Image.FromFile(file);
                   pb.Height = loadedImage.Height;
                   pb.Width = loadedImage.Width;
                   pb.Image = loadedImage;
                   flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(pb);
               }
               catch (SecurityException ex)
               {
                   // The user lacks appropriate permissions to read files, discover paths, etc.
                   MessageBox.Show("Security error. Please contact your administrator for details.\n\n" +
                       "Error message: " + ex.Message + "\n\n" +
                       "Details (send to Support):\n\n" + ex.StackTrace
                   );
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                   // Could not load the image - probably related to Windows file system permissions.
                   MessageBox.Show("Cannot display the image: " + file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf('\\'))
                       + ". You may not have permission to read the file, or " +
                       "it may be corrupt.\n\nReported error: " + ex.Message);
               }
           }
       }

    }
```

but its not working for me.i have a 8 `pictureboxes` in which 7 `picturebox` are small size and 1 `picturebox`  dimension is `width = 319,height= 277`,so please help me to select multiple images and shown them in different pictureboxes.And 7 small `pictureboxes` are in `FlowlayoutPanel` but the large `picturebox` is not in any panel

Comment: “It is not working” is not a viable problem statement. Please rework your question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: if large picture box is not in flowlayoutpanel1 then it is not created through above code

Comment: How did you set `AutoSize` and `AutoScroll`? The PBs should all be created fine with your code, provided you have `openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;`

Comment: now all picturebox in Flowlayoutpanel but it still not working.

Comment: 'AutoSize = true' and Autoscroll = false,and multiset property is set true

Comment: “It is not working” is __still__ not a viable problem statement, do you think we are mind-readers?? It works fine here.